# Oracle client in not installed or it cannot be loaded. OCIDLL cannot be loaded

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, instantclient

How it is possible that after installing Oracle11g Express and [instantclient_12_1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html) that [EMS SQL Manager for Oracle](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/oracle/manager) cannot load relevant library:

```
Oracle client in not installed or it cannot be loaded. OCIDLL cannot be loaded.
```

**Solved:**

Switching to Oracle11g 32bit and InstantClient 32bit solved the problem. Seems like x64 not supported. 
[image]

Comment: What is that "3rd party software"? Perhaps is uses JDBC or ODP.NET or OleDB or ODBC. All these drivers are not included in Oracle Instant Client, you have to install them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their docs say it's a 32 bit app.

32 bit apps can't load or use 64 bit drivers.

*Note: If you have a 64-bit version of OS, you might probably have a 64-bit Oracle client. Since SQL Manager for Oracle is a 32-bit program, it cannot work a 64-bit client. In this case you need to install a 32-bit Oracle client.*

You can always use Oracle SQL Developer for free if you have Java 8 on your machine. No need for any Oracle Client.